# Get windows identity before authentication ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

Dear stackoverflow community,

Is there any way to retrieve windows username/identity even before authentication?

To make you all understand the situation, I am currently migrating an old ASP.net application. Previous code works no problem but due to recent code migration, old code won't work anymore. I want this application to be a single sign-on instead of the user need to key in their username and password WHILE using Forms authentication method.

It involves:

- Index.aspx
- HomePage.aspx
- Login.aspx
- Global.asax

The application flow:

1. Enter global.asax and check whether isAuthenticated is true or
   false, if false, enter Index.aspx, if true, extract all the user
   accessright into .isInroles
2. If not authenticated, get the windows username, check the user
   exist in the application, and
   `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, False/True)`
   and it will redirect to global.asax and redirect to Homepage. (This
   is where single sign-on should be. And if there's no identity it
   will return to Login.aspx page.
3. User provide username and password and authenticate like normal.
   (This one works)

The thing is, when you are using Forms Authentication, the identity will return blank until the user provide one. For example `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` and other few more. Is there any way to get the windows identity before authentication?

If I change the web.config to windows authentication, it works perfectly fine but it require me to change the whole structure of the system because the way the system gave access right is very outdated using cookies .IsInRoles and my team won't agree because of time consuming process. Sorry I can't post the code snippet due to data confidentiality...

Any logical/pseudocode advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question, I restructured back the whole program authentication  by using Windows authentication, and removed the current global.asax and replace with the new one since the previous global.asax was corrupted that if I comment the whole code in the global.asax it enters. That solves my problem.